# Angular 2 standard coding style guide

Tags: angular, typescript, coding-style

I can see the style guide written by angular team over here:

> https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

and i agree with most of the guides but there is not much information about the `coding style guide` like [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/).

**Example:**

About the starting and ending of curly braces, colon on selectors, variables name etc.

**Is there any specific guide for above mentioned example?**

**I can see this set of rules on angularClass's tslint but couldn't fully understand about it:**

> https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/blob/master/tslint.json

If the question seems unclear will be happy to edit and clearify more.

Answer (score 0):

Angular team actually doesn't define it, because it's more related to the Javascript/Typescript language itself, than the framework.

What I usually follow is the [Airbnb's Javascript style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript). And for using its rules with TSLint, I use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-config-airbnb) - I'm not sure about the completeness of it versus the original ESLint version - but it looks good for me).